# Login ServerResponse match the input data

Tags: php, android

Im trying to develop login in android where i follow this tutorial https://www.android-examples.com/volley-user-login-system/. When i test, it show the echo response from `login.php` if I correctly input the data and if it is invalid.

**Correct email and pass:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbXWf.png

**Invalid email/pass:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1npp.png

login.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

include 'Config.php';

$con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

$email = $_POST['User_Email'];
$password =  $_POST['User_Password'];

$Sql_Query = "select * from tbl_UserDetails where USER_ID = '$email' and LASTNAME = '$password' ";

$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));

if(isset($check)){

echo "Data Matched";
}
else{
echo "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again !";
}

}else{
echo "Check Again";
}


?>
```

MainActivity.class

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                    // Hiding the progress dialog after all task complete.
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    // Matching server responce message to our text.
                    if(ServerResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")) {

                        // If response matched then show the toast.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Logged In Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Finish the current Login activity.

                        // Opening the user profile activity using intent.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                         startActivity(intent);
                        // Sending User Email to another activity using intent.
                        intent.putExtra("UserEmailTAG", EmailHolder);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else {


                        // Showing Echo Response Message Coming From Server.
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ServerResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }


                }
```

It should go to another activity. But what happen is just throwing the Server Response.

Comment: why use startActivity(intent); two time ?

Comment: if i use intent in Else statement. It would go to another activity even the user input is invalid. what i want is . If user input is correct in would go to another activity if invalid show only invalid input

Comment: Did you try using break point to check whether the process execution coming to the response block and if condition or not.